# My card is only displaying the back face. Why so?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a flip card memory game and the front isn't being displayed. Why so and how do I get it to be visible? I've tried `overflow: visible` but doesn't seem to effect it.

***HTML***

```
<div class="soprano-card">
            <img class="front-card" src="assets/img/Characters/Tony-Soprano.jpg" alt="Characters">
            <img class="back-card" src="assets/img/Sopranos-Title.jpg" alt="Sopranos-Title">
  </div>
```

***CSS***

````
.soprano-card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}

.front-card,
.back-card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}```

If anyone can help explain to me what I've got to do to get the front-card visible when flipped it and why at the moment it isn't would be greatly appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flip card can be created by creating a parent `div` that houses an inner `div`. Any flipping transformations can be done on the inner `div` in this example named `Flip_Card_Inner_Container`. The `Back_Face` needs to be transformed about the y-axis by 180˚. The `backface-visibility` property will prevent the images from showing through to the other side of the card.

```css
.Flip_Card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.Flip_Card_Inner_Container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.Flip_Card:hover>.Flip_Card_Inner_Container {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.Front_Face,
.Back_Face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.Front_Face {
  background-color: red;
}

.Back_Face {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Flip_Card">
  <div class="Flip_Card_Inner_Container">

    <div class="Front_Face">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    </div>
    <div class="Back_Face">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```